# Unity Mobile 2D - Select button A, then call function from button B

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Im currently working on a little 2D Android Game, and am having some issues with my Level Selection Scene.
The idea is to have several levels laid out, and when you select one it gets highlighted, and then you press the play button at the bottom of the screen to load the respective scene. (See attached image)
Now im not quite sure how to select the button and then run its function by pressing play. Im not very experienced with touch controls in Unity. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a `UIManager` or something of the sort that handles all UI related functions. Then in the `UIManager` script, you can have something like this:

```
public string level;//This would store the name of the level that was clicked on

//Create functions to assign the name when the button is clicked on
public void Level1() //This function would be assigned to level 1 button
{
    level = "Level1";
}

public void Level2() //This function would be assigned to level 2 button
{
    level = "Level2";
}
```

You can create as many functions for your level as there needs to be. Then for the play button you can have this function:

```
public void PlayGame()
{
    switch(level)
    {
        case "Level1":
            SceneManager.LoadScene(//Input the scene for level 1 here);
            break:
        //You can then create cases for the other levels too.
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

After that, you assign your script to each button in the inspector under the button component of the button in the `OnClick()` section. From here you can assign each function to the respective buttons. Also, make sure the functions are set to public so that you would be able to see them in the inspector.

For the highlighting of the button when they are clicked on, you can also change that in the inspector under the `Button` script. From there you can set the Transition style to either color change or Animation or Swap Sprite.

Comment: Oh snap that worked like a charm! I am forever in your debt kind stranger :D